# PowerShell Sort-Object -top -bottom -stable Sort

Tags: powershell, sorting

I'm trying to get the -top and -bottom parameters to work when using the Sort-Object cmdlet, I'd love some feedback about example 9 in the link, [Using Stable Sorts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6#parameters)
I thought it would be similar to the Select-Object parameters, -First 5, -last 5
I was Wrong!

```
PS C:\Users\NiceTry5> 1..20 | sort-object -bottom 5
Sort-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'bottom'.
At line:1 char:21
+ 1..20 | sort-object -bottom 5
+                     ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Sort-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SortObjec
   tCommand
```

Comment: the page you linked to shows the new[er] ps6+ additions to the cmdlet. when you look at the ps5.1 page, you will see that the `-Top/-Bottom` parameters are not available. ///// so ... what version of PoSh are you testing your code with? [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks, That was it

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error:

```
Sort-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Top'
```

it is probably because you are using PowerShell 5.x.

Check PowerShell version using command:

```
Get-Host | Select-Object Version
```

Download and install msi for [releases](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases). Note that it does not replace built-in PowerShell so you might have to run it from install location manually.